# Xmpp Python Client with Google GCM

Tags: python, xmpp, google-cloud-messaging

I want to implement a XMPP Client that connect the Google Cloud Messaging.

I have picked up the library sleekxmpp.

During the connection / authentication, my client sends the first stream required by GCM:

```
<stream:stream to='gcm.googleapis.com' xmlns:stream='http://etherx.jabber.org/streams' xmlns='jabber:client' xml:lang='en' version='1.0'>
```

But, the library is not able to parse the answer and I get the error:

```
DEBUG    Connecting to [2404:6800:4008:c00::bc]:5235
DEBUG     ==== TRANSITION disconnected -> connected
DEBUG    Starting HANDLER THREAD
DEBUG    Loading event runner
DEBUG    SEND (IMMED): <stream:stream to='gcm.googleapis.com' xmlns:stream='http://etherx.jabber.org/streams' xmlns='jabber:client' xml:lang='en' version='1.0'>
ERROR    Error reading from XML stream.
DEBUG    reconnecting...
DEBUG    SEND (IMMED): </stream:stream>
INFO     Waiting for </stream:stream> from server
DEBUG     ==== TRANSITION connected -> disconnected
DEBUG    connecting...
```

Any one has an idea why I get this?

Any example of a python XMPP connection to the GCM might be highly appreciated.

Comment: I created a python package for the same. Check this link https://github.com/winster/xmppgcm

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the use_ssl flag to True

```
xmpp = ClientXMPP('PROJECT_ID@gcm.googleapis.com', 'API_KEY')
xmpp.connect(address=('gcm.googleapis.com', 5235), use_ssl=True)
```